# 2 triggers launching sametime

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables

user_salary

```
 -------------------------
 |   user_id |  salary_p |
 -------------------------
 |    1      |    100    |
 |    2      |    200    |
 -------------------------
```

user_p_salary

```
------------------------
|   user_id |  salary_c |
-------------------------
|    1      |    100    |
|    2      |    200    |
-------------------------
```

user_salary is used via UI, and it has following trigger:

```
 create or replace trigger t$user_salary_aiu
  after insert or update of salary_p 
  on user_salary
  for each row
begin
  update user_p_salary t
  set t.salary_c = :new.salary_p,
  where t.user_id = :new.user_id
end t$user_salary_aiu;
```

user_p_salary gets data via integration and it has following code:

```
 create or replace trigger t$user_p_salary_aiu
  after insert or update of salary_c 
  on user_p_salary
  for each row
begin
  update user_salary t
  set t.salary_p = :new.salary_c,
  where t.user_id = :new.user_id
end t$user_p_salary_aiu;
```

Now the problem is that if one of the table gets the data then it executes its trigger and updates data in another table. However, a trigger on another table executes as well..which is like cycle of trigger.

The only way is to use execute immediate 'alter triggername disable' but this doesn't seem to be working in triggers at all. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I'm rather surprised you're not getting an ORA-04091 error. Are you using autonomous transactions?

Comment: yes, I am getting ORA-04901 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not only update the salary if it is not equal to the new value e.g.

```
create or replace trigger t$user_salary_aiu
  after insert or update of salary_p 
  on user_salary
  for each row
begin
  update user_p_salary t
  set t.salary_c = :new.salary_p
  where t.user_id = :new.user_id
  and (   t.salary_c <> :new.salary_p
      or (t.salary_c is null and :new.salary_p is not null)
      or (t.salary_c is not null and :new.salary_p is null) );
end t$user_salary_aiu;

create or replace trigger t$user_p_salary_aiu
  after insert or update of salary_c 
  on user_p_salary
  for each row
begin
  update user_salary t
  set t.salary_p = :new.salary_c
  where t.user_id = :new.user_id
  and (   t.salary_p <> :new.salary_c;
      or (t.salary_p is null and :new.salary_c is not null)
      or (t.salary_p is not null and :new.salary_c is null) );
end t$user_p_salary_aiu;
```

Note: Despite the wording of the documentation the dml_event_clause `update of column` appears to mean the trigger will fire if the column is included in triggering `UPDATE` statement i.e. if the column is updated, even if it is updated to the same value that it was.

Answer (score 2):

The ORA-04091 error is exactly what should happen here. In simple terms, you can't do what you're trying to do. Think about it - you update table #1, then the trigger on table #1 updates table #2, whose trigger updates table #1, whose trigger updates table #2, over and over and over. It's a trigger loop, and Oracle doesn't allow that to happen. The rule is that a row trigger cannot access a table which has already been changed (or "mutated") in the same transaction. There are techniques (notably, compound triggers) which let you "work around" this, but the best approach would be to re-work the design to eliminate this issue. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

How about you add a column to each table called BY_TRIGGER.

For an update or insert outside your trigger, you simply do not specify this column. However, when updating or inserting from within your trigger, you pass a value of 1.

Also, in each trigegr, you check if :new.BY_TRIGGER is 1, and if it is, you skip the insert/update to the other table.